stroke/strokeWeight not defined in js page
I'm a super beginner with Javascript sorry if the question is a bit silly but I've copied this code from a tutorial and it doesn't work at all when I look at the html page
stroke('green');
strokeWeight(20);
fill(0, 210, 247);

draw = function() {
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 30, 30);
}

Looking at the ispection tool it says "strokeWeight not defined"

I tried to put stroke before strokeWeight and this time it says "stroke not defined"

I must be missing something

Why do you expect those to be defined?  Are you intending to use a library which defines them and didn't include it?

What tutorial is it?

it's from khan academy

@Idontknow: Is it by chance using p5.js?  If it's using that in some kind of pre-built sandbox then to make use of it on your own page you may need to walk through the library's own tutorials/examples.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Khan Academy uses ProccessingJS (now seemingly unmaintained), the predecessor (of sorts) to p5.js, which abstracts some of the commands to display things on a canvas.
See "Using ProcessingJS outside Khan Academy" for more details on how make your Khan Academy code work outside of their editor.
Here is their example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>Processing.JS inside Webpages: Template</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--This draws the canvas on the webpage -->
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas> 
  </body>
 
  <!-- Include the processing.js library -->
  <!-- See https://khanacademy.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202260404-What-parts-of-ProcessingJS-does-Khan-Academy-support- for differences -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
  var programCode = function(processingInstance) {
    with (processingInstance) {
      size(400, 400); 
      frameRate(30);
        
      // Paste code from Khan Academy here:
      fill(255, 255, 0);
      ellipse(200, 200, 200, 200);
      noFill();
      stroke(0, 0, 0);
      strokeWeight(2);
      arc(200, 200, 150, 100, 0, PI);
      fill(0, 0, 0);
      ellipse(250, 200, 10, 10);
      ellipse(153, 200, 10, 10);
    }};

  // Get the canvas that ProcessingJS will use
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas"); 
  // Pass the function to ProcessingJS constructor
  var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, programCode); 
  </script>
</html>

You can bring in whatever code you have and replace the stuff immediately below "Paste code from Khan Academy here"
